# Rails server not working when copying back from staging deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I ssh copied a rails app from a staging server because the development repository has been lost. My goal is to create a new development code base using the deployed code as a source. So far I have removed a hidden `.bundle` folder and replaces several aliases with folders and files. I then ran `bundle install`. For the database I did a sql dump from staging and used it to build a development database. I think I'm ready to run `rails server`. But when I try to run `rails server` in the base directory. It gives me the rails command line help as if I was running `rails s` in a directory with no app.

I'm not even sure if it is possible to reverse a deploy this way. I've looked at the [rails guide on the app initialization process](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html) and all the files seem to be in place.

Comment: Are you sure that you are in the base folder of your app ?

Comment: Could you post a link to your project to see the structure ? Remember that for Rails to start up, you need bin/rails, bin/bundle, config/boot, etc.

Comment: I'm a definitely in the base folder.  My bin/directory was empty, thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderLuna Repairing the `/bin` directory fixed my problem. Thanks! If you write the comment as an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: Thank you and great to hear that it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that for Rails to start up, you need bin/rails, bin/bundle, config/boot, etc.

If you restore those files, it should work again.